# What's a freewheeling diode

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, rectifier

I was studying single phase rectifier circuit with RL load. There I found that they are using a freewheeling diode in parallel to the RL load. So is a freewheeling diode different from a power diode ? Or it is just the same with a little higher rating?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Comment: Question should be closed - lack of research.

Comment: Protection is the key word. But please investigate harder before asking here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A free wheeling or flyback diode is used to prevent damage to circuits typically with any load that has an inductor and any switching potential. An inductor can't change current immediately. Attempting to change the current rapidly such as when a switch opens after an inductor has built up energy, will cause the inductor to generate immense back EMF's.
If a flyback diode isn't present, the immense voltage will build across the switch potentially damaging it. The flyback diode gives the current through the inductor a path to continue until the energy in the inductor has dissipated (in the inductors internal resistance).

Comment: what is CO? Also I don't think you get an immense charge, you can get an immense EMF.

Comment: CO is a typo from phone's auto Predict. If a switch is involved it definitely produces an immense voltage. EMF is Electromotive force and is measured in Volts. If you're interested in some simulations, [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-inductkick.html) is one online. Any switch in a practical circuit has some capacitance value. When the inductor gets disconnected with no freewheeling path, it begins driving current through the capacitance of the switch, which builds up a massive voltage, as you can see in the simulation it reaches 2.2kV.

Comment: Sorry I now realize you may have been confused with the terminology. It produces both a charge and a voltage. Voltage is just the measure of potential energy between 2 points per unit of charge. Capacitance is measured in the ratio of charge to voltage, so by building up a voltage you also build up a charge.

Comment: I'm not confused by the terminology. The voltage (EMF) produced by the inductor is proportional to the rate of change of current through it. The energy stored by the inductor is proportional to the current through it. Current flowing into the switch capacitance will cause the capacitor to charge, and the voltage across it to increase, but the charge in Coulombs will not be immense, it will be proportional to the energy originally stored in the inductor, it will be distinctly finite - and would be the same if the current through the inductor is reduced slowly or rapidly.

Comment: It is distinctly finite, but the voltage generated on the capacitor does reach much higher levels than originally in the inductor. This is due to the current not being able to change instantly and being driven through the switch when it's in the off state, now being modelled by a capacitor. Capacitors themselves have something known as Equivalent Series Resistance (ESR). At any given instant, current is constant, therefore the voltage across the switch is then V = I*ESR. If the ESR of the switch is large, the switch will experience a very large voltage applied to it.

Comment: I think you will find that the voltage across a capacitor most of the time is dominated by the charge on it V=Q/C rather than the voltage generated by current through the ESR which tends to be very low. I'm not disagreeing that without the freewheel diode you get a large voltage across the switch, just that it is produced by the rate of change of current through the inductor, rather than from charging up the switch capacitor - that is an effect not a cause.

Comment: Yes that is the voltage across a capacitor in normal operation, but it isn't acting normally. I was never suggesting that the capacitance was the cause of the voltage, it is the combination of the ESR and the inability of the inductor to change current instantaneously. However, you're incorrect in discounting ESR, and the theory agrees with [that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) (derivation section), denoted R2 here, large resistance causes larger change in current, generating more voltage. The ESR of the switch is, aside from the inductor itself, the major factor of back EMF.

Comment: Capacitors always act normally. Where in that reference does it mention ESR? or even capacitance? Even resistance only gets mentioned twice - switch resistance which is obviously high - and this is not ESR - and inductor resistance.

Comment: "If there is no flyback diode but only something with a great resistance (such as the air between two metal contacts), say, R2, we will approximate it as:" the resistance they are talking about is for a mechanical switch, however in an electronic switch such as a mosfet, which acts like a very low value capacitor when off will have some ESR value. It's not acting normally in the sense that typically, capacitive resistance is never accounted for in standard calculations, but here it is the cause of a major problem.

Comment: ESR isn't the DC resistance across the capacitor - that is the leakage resistance. It is the resistance in *series* with the capacitance - it is used to model a real capacitor as an ideal capacitor in series with a resistor, see http://my.ece.ucsb.edu/York/Bobsclass/194/References/General/ESR%20of%20Capacitors.pdf ESR's are typically quite low see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance - the highest ESR listed in typical values is 30 Ohms. I don't know what ESR's are for silicon switches, but its not going to be massively higher.

Comment: ESR for actual capacitors are quite low, but a switch isn't a manufactured capacitor, it'd something that has capacitor like properties when in a certain state. They're manufactured to be incredibly high impedance devices when in an off state. ESR is its off state resistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31551/discussion-between-icy-and-thallazar).

Answer (score 3):

The freewheeling diode, for power rectifier applications, usually is a diode of the same type as used in the rectifier. This improves manufacturability.

The function of this diode is to provide a path for the current generated by the back emf when the rectifier is loaded with an RL circuit. Thus, damage to components of recitificador are avoided.

Comment: Freewheel diodes are applied to the inductive loads not really to do with power rectifiers. Why do you get a back EMF?

Comment: @Icy The answer is about a rectifier. I think that "rectifier" here is used as general term. Of course, the freewheeling diode aplies on controlled rectifiers than basic rectifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an RL load, it's always good to have a diode connected in reverse biased across the inductor. This diode is called freewheeling diode. It's purpose is to block the back emf generated by a coil whenever power is disconnected from this. This back emf could damage other components in the circuit especially solid state components.

Comment: It doesn't block the back EMF - it provides a path by which the inductor current can continue to flow when the original source is disconnected.